# How to create simple readable regex that matches either of two possible file paths (for Jest test script)

Tags: regex, typescript, visual-studio-code, jestjs

Apologies if this question is already answered, but all of the answers I've found recommend regex that's extremely difficult to parse, and I'm hopeful that something more readable should be possible.

I am running tests using Jest on a Javascript project using typescript.

Using the default build runner in VS Code, and configured in `tsconfig.json` (code below), my transpiled javascript goes to an `out` folder.

I have a few sub-folders containing little test projects. I would like to run tests just for one of those sub-folders. I had this working via the "scripts" section in `package.json` (code below). But then I added the `out` folder and now the tests can't find the transpiled javascript.

I'd like to tell Jest that there are TWO folders it needs to look in when running tests - the folder where the test file and typescript lives, and the folder where the transpiled javascript lives.

The current line - `"test:char": "jest --watchAll --testPathPattern=src/character-copier"` just specifies one folder and is using regex but this isn't obvious, which suits me fine because it means it's easy to read. I'd like to be able to say "Look in either `src/character-copier` or `out/character-copier`" - but I can't work out how to do this.

package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "test:char": "jest --watchAll --testPathPattern=src/character-copier"
  },
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "out"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To find files within a specific directory.

```
/(out|src)\/character-copier\/.*/gi
```

demo: https://regex101.com/r/F49pNG/1

---

Use this to execute your code:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --watchAll --testPathPattern=\"/(out|src)\/character-copier\/.*\""
  },
```